# Can I use my Android device as remote control for my SmartTV?

Tags: remote-control, smart-tv

<sup>As a similar question was deleted by its owner while I wrote up the answer, I decided to share it this way.</sup>

I have a Samsung SmartTV, and want to use my Android device to remote-control it – including switching TV channels, adjusting volume and, if possible, the full spectrum of features the SmartTV offers. My Android device does not have an IR blaster, and I'm not speaking of "buying additional hardware" for it.

Is this possible – and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple possibilities to remote-control your Samsung TV with your Android device. For one, there are a bunch of [Samsung TV remote control apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_mmdevices#group_680) giving you a wide range of choices.

A second variant would involve [FHEM](http://fhem.de/) on your PC (this is a home automation software, and there's a module available for Samsung TVs – I use this, so I can vouch for it) and, optionally, the [andFHEM](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=li.klass.fhem) Android app. This way you cannot only use your Android device, but any device with a web browser to remote control the TV – and even integrate it with some other (home) automation stuff. For example, using [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) you could have your TV turned off (or mute it) whenever you receive a call on your Android device – or turn it on as soon as your device connects to your local WiFi. Much more is possible, of course :)

Answer (score 0):

I've used https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tv.peel.smartremote an my Samsung TV, works fine and can connect to my set top box too.

Comment: for a TV remote, this app is far too much intruding to privacy: 26 permissions required, a.o. to accounts, contacts and calendar, rises the question what it controls remotely (or what it's controlled by). The app description doesn't tell (though one might argue "reminders to watch a show later" might explain calendar access). That's why my answer doesn't specify any RC app but links to a list of such, so everybody can make his/her own pick.